# How to enable logging for requests_oauthlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I'm trying to enable logging to stdout for `requests_oauthlib`. The [example in the docs](https://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/real_world_example_with_refresh.html) suggests this:

```
# Uncomment for detailed oauthlib logs
#import logging
#import sys
#log = logging.getLogger('oauthlib')
#log.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout))
#log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

But it doesn't seem to have any effect. What's the proper way to do it?

Comment: you uncomment this strings? you put this code BEFORE making requests? console is still empty?

Comment: Yes (to all of the above)

Comment: ok. maybe need to use not sys.stdout, but sys.stderrors. you should pass you output console to StreamHandler

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The root logger's name should be `requests_oauthlib`, i.e. the package name. The modules in the package [define loggers](https://github.com/requests/requests-oauthlib/blob/v1.0.0/requests_oauthlib/oauth2_session.py#L10) like this

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

so configuring the root logger as described in the example should work:

```
import logging
import sys
log = logging.getLogger('requests_oauthlib')
log.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout))
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```